# Shell rm rf directory under MacOS

Tags: macos, bash

On MacOS, I have a bash script where I delete a full directory hierarchy: `rm -rf "/mydirectory/here"`
Once every 3-4 runs, I go a `/mydirectory/here: Directory not empty`
And the folder is empty, except a ".DS_Store" file.
I guess that when the rmrf delete files in the directory, MacOS modify the root `.DS_Store` in parallel and the rmrf cannot then delete the 'emptied' directory, since the DS_Store appeared again.
Any ideas ?

Comment: To prevent failure it might work to rename the directory first and remove it after. Or remove write-access before removing, or just remove twice.

Comment: @anubhava the problem is different: I do not want to avoid DS_Store creation, this is a shell script committed on a source repository, and I don't have the hand on the executing machine. Could you remove the duplicate tag please ?

Comment: Actually solution to your problem is in the question I've linked. Unless you stop this file's auto-creation there will be errors like this in `rm -rf` command.

Comment: @anubhava I don't understand, it's not a solution, it's a workaround !?

Comment: Since this is default OSX behavior you will get workaround type solutions only

Comment: I recently removed 'rm -rf' from a script of mine, after a bug deleted ALL my backup archives for this one app I have.  Didn't even notice for months.  I'll delete them by hand from now on.
.DS_Store is put there by the finder when you open a directory.  I'd try rm mydir/.DS_Store; rmdir mydir all in one line.